# MD5 with salt in PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, security, hash, md5

I need a common hashing method both in php and javascript, something like MD5 or if not MD5 then something to use salt, but to generate same result from php and javascript.

What I wanted to do is, I have a series of questions that I will ask user and users has to answer them, but to make it fast and avoid delay to check the user answers from server, I also want to load the answers with questions and match them in javascript as users answer them. Now I need to bring the answers hashed from php server, and when I am matching them with users answers, I would hash the user answer and match it with the hashed answer from server.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is little more than obfuscation what you are doing. Presumably you want to prevent the users from cheating. Doing so and relying on client side code won't work securely.

When the client browser receives the answer hashes and the corresponding salts, the user can simply brute force the correct answers. The number of possible answers is so small that the user can try every possible answer with the received salt and find the matching answer by comparing the hashes.

Since this is nothing more than obfuscation, why make it complicated? Simply encode your correct answers with Base 64 or something like that. This will prevent most users from cheating. If you actually want to make sure that no user can cheat, you need to send the selected answers to the server.

---

If you actually want to go ahead with your plan, the fastest MD5 hasher for JavaScript right now is [SparkMD5](https://github.com/satazor/SparkMD5), not that you need the speed for your use case. [CryptoJS](https://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/) also implements MD5 and PHP has the [`md5()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) function. All those implementations are compatible. You just have to make sure that you use the same encoding (Character encoding and Hex/Base64).

A construction with a salt may be `md5(answer || salt)` where `||` denotes concatenation. This is not really save, but it doesn't matter in your case anyway.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. its not fully secure, but I don't want to make it too obvious for them. and because these questions will have a time limit, so they don't have enough time to dig that deep.